# Where can I find phpunit.sh after installation on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

Like in subject I have installed phpunit but cant find phpunit.sh file to pass path to netbeans.

But I checked

> phpunit -version

and recive

> PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

So i think the installation is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is just `phpunit` (in my system is in /usr/bin/phpunit).

In NetBeans in Tools > Options > PHP > Unit testing, just specify the output of `which phpunit`.

Comment: Bingo. No `.sh` extension on PHPUnit's shell script.

Comment: This used to work just fine for me. But I recently installed netbeans 7.1 and I am now getting a message saying my version is to old and needs to be version 3.3.0 or higher even though I have version 3.5.5-2 installed. Any idea why this is?